# Eclipse: key binding for getting a list of attributes of a class

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, Ctrl + O gives a list of all methods available in the class. Do you know any key binding that gives a list of all attributes of a certain class?

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the [Outline view](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm) are editor specific. When viewing Java classes, the Outline view of Eclipse shows the attributes of the class, too.

Maybe you've just hidden your fields. This can be done by the following icon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the view Outline goto `Window -> Show View -> Outline` Key binding for this view is ALT + SHIFT + Q, O

and also make sure not to filter fields in this view

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> , <kbd>V</kbd>.

If you want more eclipse shortcut keys, press

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

[image: Eclipse Shortcut]